# randomize function implementation

Tags: java, random

Say I have a method in a class that carries out movement (call it move(Earth)). The function is implemented in another class using inheritance and such like this:

animal.move(Earth)

Is it possible to randomize the actual implementation without messing with the function method?

```
public void rMove(Earth myEarth) throws InterruptedException
{
    int x = (int) location.getX();
    int y = (int) location.getY();
    int xMax = myEarth.getX() - 1;
    int yMax = myEarth.getY() - 1;
    double w = Math.random();
    int rMove = (int) (w + Math.random()*4);

    switch(rMove)
    {
        case NOR:
            location.setLocation(x,y-1);
            break;
        case SOU:
            location.setLocation(x,y+1);
            break;
        case EAS:
            location.setLocation(x+1,y);
            break;
        case WES:
            location.setLocation(x-1,y);
            break;
    }
}
```

The class containing this method is extended into another class

```
public class Carnivore extends Animal
```

Within the class carnivore, the animal moves using the above function like this:

```
super.rMove(myEarth);
```

There's a whole bunch of other code involving the movement but I don't think it's relevant. My question is how to modify the above implementation without modifying the actual rMove.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you have done so far? Do you mean changing the implementation of the method without changing its signature?

Comment: I updated my question with the move method. This class is extended into another class, so I can use the function in another class, Animal. My question is, can I modify the implementation of the function Animal.Move(Earth) without modifying the original method?

Comment: You want to modify a method without modifying the method? Why do you think that would be possible?

Comment: I don't know. But the Move function is used in multiple classes, and I want to be able to randomize the movement of each individual class so that not all move at the same rate.

Comment: Refactor the things you wish to be able to modify out of this method and override those. Can you give one example of exactly what you'd want to be able to change?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at having a separate method for the randomisation logic that can be overridden by the subclasses of Animal. I'm not a Java developer so the syntax might not be completely correct, but this gives you an idea. For example:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract int moveRandom();
}

public class Carnivore extends Animal
{
    public int moveRandom() {
        double w = Math.random();
        int rMove = (int) (w + Math.random()*4);
        return rMove;
    }
}


public void rMove() {
    int rMove = this.rMove();
}
```